# How to find all unique combinations out of two list in python?

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have two lists:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['e', 'f', 'g']
```

And I want to generate all possible combinations of their pairings

Desired Output:
[image: (('a', 'f'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'g')) (('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g')) (('a', 'e'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'f')) (('a', 'g'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e')) (('a', 'g'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')) (('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'e'))]

What is the best way to do it?

Right now I have written this code which works but seems highly inefficient.

[image: See code here]

Comment: You only need permutations of the second list. Also, please don't share code as images.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to permute the second list:

```
from itertools import permutations
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['e', 'f', 'g']

pairs = [tuple(zip(l1, p)) for p in permutations(l2)]
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
[(('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g')),
 (('a', 'e'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'f')),
 (('a', 'f'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'g')),
 (('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'e')),
 (('a', 'g'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')),
 (('a', 'g'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to think about this is that each set of output values is the result of pairing the elements of the first list with some permutation of the elements of the second list.  So you just need to generate all possible permutations if n elements, then use that as a permutation of the elements of the second list, pairing them with the elements of the first list.

The most flexible way to implement it is by defining a simple generator function:

```
from itertools import permutations

def gen_perm_pairs(l1, l2):
    cnt = len(l1)
    assert len(l2) == cnt

    for perm in permutations(range(cnt)):
        yield tuple((l1[i], l2[perm[i]]) for i in range(cnt))
```

You can then call it to generate the desired results:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['e', 'f', 'g']

for pairs in gen_perm_pairs(l1, l2):
    print(pairs)
```

This produces the following:

```
(('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g'))
(('a', 'e'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'f'))
(('a', 'f'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'g'))
(('a', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'e'))
(('a', 'g'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f'))
(('a', 'g'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e'))
```

Comment: In my experience, python code is often way easier to read (and also slightly faster) when iterating on elements directly rather than on indices. In particular, any code that contains `for ... in ... range(len(seq)):` can almost-always be rewritten in a better way `for ... in seq:` or `for ... in enumerate(seq):` or `for ... in zip(seq, ...):` or something similar. In this case, your loop can be rewritten `for perm in permutations(l2): yield tuple(l1[i], perm[i] for i in range(len(l2)))` or even better `for perm in permutations(l2): yield tuple(zip(l1,perm))`

Comment: @Stef Yes, generating the indices was unnecessary, since the elements of the second list can be permuted directly without the need for indices.  Even better, the entire function body can be replaced by `return (tuple(zip(l1, p2)) for p2 in permutations(l2))`, which returns a generator without even needing an explicit `yield`.  I would have updated my answer, but someone else had already posted a solution that permuted the elements directly.